# Cinema4D: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: windows, cinema-4d

Everytime I open Cinema 4D R18, I get this message:

[The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQzH0.png)

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (Version 1703, Build 15063.413) and I've made sure I'm on the latest version of Windows and .NET framework.

There's one way I've found to get it to work and it happens everytime I finish installing the program and I tick "run after the setup is complete". C4D works perfectly but once I close it, I get this message everytime I want to open it again.

After thouroughly looking online for a solution, I still havent found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a no license version?

1. Uninstall and reinstall latest Microsoft Visual C++ runtime packages and do the same thing with .net framework, update directX.
2. Run cinema 4d as admin.
3. Try signing into another user account and open it.
4. Search if any dll missing in your cinema 4d directory while installing due to anti-virus(it may be deleted by your anti-virus).
5. Check if any registry errors( i had this problem while ago with cinema 4d r16).

Restart your PC :)